# convert json string to variables

Tags: php, json

maybe my question is a bit unreasonable, but what's wrong i ask.

I have a simple script like below

```
<?php
$r['code'] = 200;
$r['result'] = "hello world";
$r['down'][0] = "first";
$r['down'][1] = "second";
echo json_encode($r, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

and the results from the script are

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "result": "hello world",
  "down": [
    "first",
    "second"
  ]
}
```

as seen above, that variables can be converted to json by using json_encode, and to my question, can we change json back into variables?

for example

Before

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "result": "hello world",
  "down": [
    "first",
    "second"
  ]
}
```

After

```
<?php
$r['code'] = 200;
$r['result'] = "hello world";
$r['down'][0] = "first";
$r['down'][1] = "second";
echo json_encode($r, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Comment: Look at `json_decode`... or if in the same script `$r` should still be accessible.

Comment: `json_encode` returns json array but will not actually convert `$r` unless you do something like `$r = json_encode($r, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` simply put you already have your `$r` in original form

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/extract):

```
$json = '{
  "code": 200,
  "result": "hello world",
  "down": [
    "first",
    "second"
  ]
}';

$r = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($r);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [code] => 200
    [result] => hello world
    [down] => Array
        (
            [0] => first
            [1] => second
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

yes we can accomplished that by using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$a =  json_decode($r, true);
```

True is used to say that we want use regular Array

```
$array['item']
```

if false is set, the property will be accessed by using

```
$array->item
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode()` to convert JSON array to PHP array.

```
$json_array = '{
  "code": 200,
  "result": "hello world",
  "down": [
    "first",
    "second"
  ]
}';

$r = json_decode($json_array);
```